# RequiredFieldValidator always invalid

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have three `RequiredFieldValidator` controls on the form (for a dropdown and textboxes) and they always invalidate the page even if user enters data!

```
<div class="control-group">
            <asp:Label ID="HouseTypeLabel" runat="server" Text="Type of home" class="control-label asterisk" meta:resourcekey="HouseTypeLabelResource1"></asp:Label>
            <div class="controls">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="HouseType" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="HouseTypeResource1">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="please select" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="rancher" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource2"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="two-storey" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource3"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="bi-level" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource4"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="bungalow" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource5"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="bungalow + basement" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource6"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <p class="help-block">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="HouseType" runat="server" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="Please indicate type of home" meta:resourcekey="RequiredFieldValidator1Resource1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
            </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
            <asp:Label ID="TotalBedroomsLabel" runat="server" Text="Total number of bedrooms" class="control-label asterisk" AssociatedControlID="TotalBedrooms" meta:resourcekey="TotalBedroomsLabelResource1"></asp:Label>
           <div class="controls">
              <asp:TextBox ID="TotalBedrooms" runat="server" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="" meta:resourcekey="TotalBedroomsResource1"></asp:TextBox>
            <p class="help-block">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ControlToValidate="TotalBedrooms" EnableClientScript="False" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter total number of bedrooms" meta:resourcekey="RequiredFieldValidator2Resource1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </p>
          </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
            <asp:Label ID="TotalBathroomsLabel" runat="server" Text="Total number of bathrooms" class="control-label asterisk" AssociatedControlID="TotalBathrooms" meta:resourcekey="TotalBathroomsLabelResource1"></asp:Label>
           <div class="controls">
              <asp:TextBox ID="TotalBathrooms" runat="server" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="" meta:resourcekey="TotalBathroomsResource1"></asp:TextBox>
            <p class="help-block">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" EnableClientScript="false" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TotalBathrooms" ErrorMessage="Please enter total number of bathrooms" meta:resourcekey="RequiredFieldValidator3Resource2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </p>
          </div>
</div>
```

So it does not matter whether I enter data or do not enter anything, when I click submit button the three error messages are displayed.

Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT: the submit button is below

```
<div class="control-group">
<!-- Button -->
<div class="controls">
    <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Save and Next" class="btn btn-info" meta:resourcekey="SubmitButtonResource1" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the meta:resources on the validators (just for testing)?

Comment: Can you debug? does postback fire?

Comment: Postback does fire, removing meta:resources does not do anything.

Comment: Close your visual studio and start again. Just thought!

Comment: It turns out everything is working fine. What was happening is that I had the form pre-populated with data on `Page_Load()` and before populating I did not use `if(!Page.IsPostBack){ /* populate fields here*/ }`. So before my `SubmitButton_Click()` fired the fields were over-written with old (and in my case blank) values. That is why the `RequiredFieldValidator` controls would fire. Thanks everyone for input.

Comment: How many form You have? Are You sure you have just one form in one page? Or you have many form? in one page? Please attach 3 error message. If many form in a page use validation group.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `ValidationGroup` attribute for your required field validators.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2"  
                            ControlToValidate="TotalBedrooms" 
                            runat="server" 
                            ErrorMessage="Please enter total number of  bedrooms" 
                            ValidationGroup="vgSave">      // add this for all your required field validators and also the button event that invokes them
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Note: Add `ValidationGroup` to all the required field validators and also the button event that invokes them. Make sure you dont change the name. Keep it same for all.

Comment: I added the `ValidationGroup="vgSave"` as you mentioned but it did not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late for the original poster, but in case anyone else has the same issue:

I spent an hour today getting frustrated as to why a seemingly correct RequiredFieldValidator always returned false in Visual Studio 2012.

I tried restarting VS and clean/rebuild, nothing was working.

In the end, I renamed the ID of the target TextBox control, and pointed the RequiredFieldValidator at the new name. It worked immediately.

One of those VS 'features' I suppose.

I'm guessing something got messed up in the auto-generated code for the old RequiredFieldValidator object or something, but I never looked further into it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem that was a lot like this, i had a usercontrol with validators and a validation group.

Now i placed this usercontrol two times on a page and only showed one of them at a time..

The result of this was that the visible ValidationSummary Showed the errors from both controls, so even if the currently visible usercontrol was valid it resulted in error messages in the ValidationSummary.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="HouseType" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="HouseTypeResource1">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="please select" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource1"></asp:ListItem>

          ....
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="HouseType" runat="server" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="Please indicate type of home" meta:resourcekey="RequiredFieldValidator1Resource1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

To be like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="HouseType" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="HouseTypeResource1">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="please select" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="HouseType" InitialValue="-1"  runat="server" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="Please indicate type of home" meta:resourcekey="RequiredFieldValidator1Resource1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

I think you should give value at default value.

```
<asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="please select" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource1"></asp:ListItem>
```

So highlight this part: **Value="-1"**

and at asp:RequiredFieldValidator You should put **InitialValue**

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="HouseType" InitialValue="-1"  runat="server" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="Please indicate type of home" meta:resourcekey="RequiredFieldValidator1Resource1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Re-try and if that answer is not working let me know.

Answer (score -1):

you should try remove `EnableClientScript="false"` out of your asp.net tag.

Comment: No I don't want any client side validation to happen. Thanks for the idea though.